# Flutter didChangeAppLifecycleState stopped working in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, background

Please help!!!

Here is a sample of my code (only important parts extracted)

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused: 
       AuraPreferences.queryPreference('AppointmentRemindMe').then((value) async {
          if (appState.isUserLoggedIn && AuraConvert.toBoolean(value)) {
            // stop foreground and resume background appointment reminders
            AppointmentReminder.stop();
            await AppointmentReminder.scheduleRemindersInBackground();
          }
        });

        ProgressNoteService.stop();
        chatMessageProvider.stopConnection();

        _goneToBackgroundAt = DateTime.now().toUtc();

        appState.cancelSsoTimer();

        print('App went to background at $_goneToBackgroundAt');
        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
```

---

```
  static Future<void> scheduleRemindersInBackground() async {
    // schedule appointment reminders in background 10 minutes before they are supposed to occur
    final appointments = await ScheduleService.getAppointmentReminders(inNextMinutes: 60 * 24 * 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
      await _scheduleReminderInBackground(
```

---

```
  static Future<List<AuraAppointment>> getAppointmentReminders({required int inNextMinutes}) async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    now = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute);
    final to = now.add(Duration(minutes: inNextMinutes));

    if (cacheAppointments.containsKey(DateTimeRange(start: now, end: to))) {
      return cacheAppointments[DateTimeRange(start: now, end: to)] ?? <AuraAppointment>[];
    }

    var appointments = await getAppointments(now, to);
```

---

```
class ScheduleService {
  static Future<List<AuraAppointment>> getAppointments(
    DateTime? dateFrom,
    DateTime? dateTo, {
    isCalledFromCalendar = false,
    isSync = false,
  }) async {
    if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null) return <AuraAppointment>[];

    final authUser = await UserService.authUser;

       final String uri = 'https://api.domain123.com/something_here_to_send_parameters';

    final networkHelper = NetworkHelper(uri, authUser: authUser, goToLoginScreen: isCalledFromCalendar);

    var appointments = await networkHelper.get<List<AuraAppointment>>((dynamic data) {
      return (data as List).map((i) => AuraAppointment.fromMap(i)).toList();
    });

    final localDb = await MobileDatabase.dbInstance;

    if (NetworkHelper.isConnected) {
      if (appointments == null) return <AuraAppointment>[];

      if (isSync) {
        await MobileDatabase.deleteData('AuraAppointments', {'OwnerID': authUser?.userId});
      }

      // upsert data into local database to be available in off-line mode
      for (var appointment in appointments) {
        appointment.ownerId = authUser?.userId;
        MobileDatabase.upsertData('AuraAppointments', appointment.toMap());
      }
    } else {
      appointments = (await localDb.query(
        'AuraAppointments',
        where: 'OwnerID = ?',
        whereArgs: [authUser?.userId],
      ))
          .map((i) => AuraAppointment.fromMap(i))
          .toList();
    }

    final individualApp = appointments.where((a) => a.scgrID == 0);
    individualApp.forEach((ia) {
      if (ia.clientID != null && ia.clientID! > 0) ia.clientIDs.add(ia.clientID);
    });

    final groupApp = appointments.where((a) => a.scgrID! > 0 && a.clientID == 0);
    groupApp.forEach((ga) {
      final clients =
          appointments!.where((a) => a.scgrID == ga.scgrID && a.clientID! > 0).map((a) => a.clientID).toList();
      ga.clientIDs.addAll(clients);
    });

    var resultApp = <AuraAppointment>[];
    resultApp.addAll(individualApp);
    resultApp.addAll(groupApp);

    return resultApp;
  } // end of getAppointments method
```

---

The notifications works correctly when the app is in the offline mode but doesn't work when it is in online mode. The appointments (data) come from local DB in offline mode and web API in online mode. It means that web API fails when it is called at the time when the app is pushed to the background. This happens only in release builds for iOS (Android is good) but not in debug builds when I run the code on my iPhone 8 device.
PLEASE HELP ME SOLVE THIS PROBLEM!!!

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)

Android Studio (version 4.2)

iOS version is 14.4

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest Flutter channel stable version (2.5.1)? Wishful thinking but maybe that'll fix it.

Comment: I've just tested my code using the latest Flutter 2.5.1. Here is what I found. My mobile app is running in online mode which means it calls web APIs. When I push it to the background I get no notifications. However, when I resume my app to the foreground then I get notification. This is opposite of what I what to achieve. It appears to me that there is something wrong in Flutter SDK.

Comment: Are you just trying to wake your backgrounded app up with a pre-scheduled local or external notification (like a push notification), or are you trying to have your backgrounded app send a notification when backgrounded? AFAIK on iOS backgrounded apps have execution suspended except for those that use some very specific system APIs, like audio and navigation. In our app I can foreground it if it's in the background using a pre-scheduled local notification, and it works on iOS and Android, but the notification has to either be external or scheduled before the app is backgrounded.

Comment: My app is supposed to send appointment reminders in a form of local push notifications (using flutter_local_notifications package) all the time. While it's active I run a timer every 10 minutes to selected an upcoming appointment and remind a user. When the app is pushed to the background I kill the timer and make web API call to select appointments and schedule notifications for them 10 minutes before their start. This happens under case AppLifecycleState.paused: in didChangeAppLifecycleState()              I'm sure this used to work months ago when I was referencing Flutter SDK ver 1.?.?